# I attacked someone and now they are mad. How can I calm them down so I can talk to them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I attacked someone and now they are mad.  How can I calm them down so I can talk to them?

I would like a permanent solution (not something that just lasts for a few min).

I am on the PC so if there is a console command I am good to try that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yield to them - sheath your weapons.

Unless they *really* dislike you (like Bandits, or a several thousand gold bounty, for instance) they will stop fighting once you do that.

Comment: I think it may also depend on your bounty when it comes to guards. I've tried yielding to guards after killing lots of them and they didn't stop attacking.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your bounty, or use the spell Calm on them and talk to them then. I know you said not for a few minutes but now that you have the calmed and on your quest, they probably wont be mad.

Answer (score 0):

Use stamina potions to run far away, then crouch in a bush until you're hidden. Then use the wait option and wait 24 hours twice, then you should be good for people being mad at you. But the guards wont forget, but they should not attack on sight anymore.